# Problems With Toc/Mac

Tags: mac

First time using and installing Tor.

I click on "Connect" and "Remove Definitions and Connect".. and it give me the message: "Impossible to save the Tor Configurations"..

The log is:

30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges") 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
30/11/17 23:59:43.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
30/11/17 23:59:44.000 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
30/11/17 23:59:44.000 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
30/11/17 23:59:44.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 192.168.0.1:9150 
30/11/17 23:59:44.000 [WARN] Could not bind to 192.168.0.1:9150: Can't assign requested address 
30/11/17 23:59:44.000 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.

How can I solve this problem?

I m using Mac OS High Sierrra.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this Tor Browesr? I'm assuming this is Tor Browser.

Do you have any idea why Tor Browser is trying to open its SocksPort on 192.168.0.1 instead of 127.0.0.1? Did you change its settings or its torrc? Does your computer not have a loopback interface with 127.0.0.0/8 available?

192.168.0.1 looks a lot like the IP address of a home router. Are you sure your computer has that as a local IP address? If this is the IP of your home router, why is it appearing in your Tor logs?

The key log line is `[WARN] Could not bind to 192.168.0.1:9150: Can't assign requested address`. For some reason Tor Browser thinks it should open its SocksPort on that IP address and port, but I do not think your computer has that IP address.

> I click on "Connect" and "Remove Definitions and Connect".. and it give me the message: "Impossible to save the Tor Configurations"..

This is very unusual. Where are you seeing this? Did you change Tor Browser's settings before this point? Did you ever try changing the permissions or ownership of its files? (don't!) Did you try running it as root? (dont't!) Where did you get Tor Browser? How did you install it?

If you want to fix this by uninstalling Tor Browser and installing it again ...

1. To uninstall Tor Browser, open your applications folder and drag Tor Browser into the trash.
2. Delete the folder `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data` (The `~` means its in your home folder)
3. Download Tor Browser from https://torproject.org
4. Mount the download .dmg image file
5. In the window that opens, drag the Tor Browser icon into the applications folder *in that window*. Do not simply double click on the Tor Browser icon. After it copies into the applications folder, close the window.